# ASP.NET MVC subproperty's deserialization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, deserialization

I have two identical dropdownlists for identical subproperties of my item TaskViewModel.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.AssignedTo.ID, TaskHelper.GetUsersSelect(Model.AssignedTo), new { @class = "select" })

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Controller.ID, TaskHelper.GetUsersSelect(Model.Controller), new { @class = "select" })
```

Both values **sending** on posting form (...*&AssignedTo.ID=1&Controller.ID=1*...), but I always get only task.AssignedTo deserialized

```
  public ActionResult SaveTask(TaskViewModel task)
  {
      task.AssignedTo.ID //value here
      task.Controller.ID //null reference exception
  }

  public class TaskViewModel
  {
      public UserViewModel Controller { get; set; }
      public UserViewModel AssignedTo{ get; set; }
  }

  public class UserViewModel
  {
     public long ID { get; set; }
     public string Title { get; set; }
  }
```

What may be a reason for that strange behaviour?

Comment: Could you show your view models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `Controller` is a reserved keyword and the default model binder doesn't like it. Try renaming the property:

```
public class TaskViewModel
{
    public UserViewModel TaskController { get; set; }
    public UserViewModel AssignedTo { get; set; }
}
```

The whole problem comes from the ValueProvider that the default model binder uses. When it encounters the `Controller` navigation property it does this:

```
var value = ValueProvider.GetValue("Controller");
```

which unfortunately first looks at route data and after that in query string. So this returns "Home" or whatever the name of the controller is and obviously trying to assign the string "Home" to a class of type `UserViewModel` cannot result in success.